# How to manage imports in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, import

So I've recently started using Typescript. Both for the back end (nodejs) and front end, and I'm started to feel an urge to chew on my own arm every time I have to add a new import.

Coming from the .NET world the last 15 years I've come to appreciate the more or less automatic type resolving. Especially with a background in C/C++, which whenever I return to, remind me of the #include hell that ever so often becomes the case. Given what I am now facing, I get a feeling of "those were the days".

I typically prefer to keep my code as one class -> one file (with some obv exceptions for smaller stuff). This results in a lot of files and even more imports. I recently discovered some tools that help out creating the imports but it is still really annoying.

I get it that the underlying JS needs these imports (in various ways depending on module system) But given how easy these tools resolves the imports. Would it not be possible for the compiler to simply generate them? In the rare case of ambiguity the compiler would simple give an error and the user needs to resolve it manually.

Typescript seems to be a great language otherwise but this is really close to a deal breaker for me. Or am I missing something? Can this be done in a better way?

Comment: you can create an index.ts file per folder, which then you can use to import.. help in solving the problem to a very large extent

Comment: Right, I've actually done something similar. In each folder I have a file called _[folderName].ts (otherwise I get a lot of index.ts tabs). However, I still get import { A, B, C, ... } from ".../_stuff". Although this is better than one line for each, it's not close to good enough. The import * as xyz from ".../stuff" sometimes makes it somewhat easier. Though it implies the annoying xyz.A everywhere. I just want to use A.

Comment: Use WebStorm. Or wait for the next version of VS Code, which should use TS 2.6. There is a bullet point _"Automatic imports from completion lists"_ in [the roadmap for TS 2.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#26-october-2017).

Comment: Maybe because you're used to C#/.NET it may feel different since things are "automatically" available if they're part of the same package. But in JS/TS, much like any other language, you need to be explicit about what you're importing and why. Especially in JS, order matters, so it's not as easy as auto-resolving names. Your best bet is to install some tool that automatically imports things for you on your editor upon autocompletion.